# Mixed Content: Rewrite Javascript to use HTTPS-only

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using loads of javascript on my Website and my Website throws out Mixed Content Warnings (about 30 of them, telling me, I am using "Scripts of unsafe sources") and as I'm not into javascript that much, I wanted to ask if (and if yes, if you know it) there is away to add a script to rewrite my javascript http requests.

Comment: This warning is usually thrown because a page has been called using https:// but contains some assets (normally media or scripts) which are not hosted at a https:// endpoint. You should secure all assets using TLS. To your second question, you could use a server side Javascript framework such as node.js to rewrite http requests but it wouldn't be a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you should remove all http and https references from your links. That means that this link:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

should be rewritten as:

```
//www.google.com/
```

If you do that, the browser will automatically add http or https, depending on which protocol your webpage is currently using. Doing this will allow you to move over to HTTPS whenever you'd like with minimal impact.

Note that some websites still don't support HTTPS, so in those cases you'll have to use HTTP. However, you really should never request any HTTP resources if you are on HTTPS because browsers will display your site as insecure to users.